# AppWidget with SharedPreferences has to update twice

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-appwidget

I'm building a Widget which displays a textview which is editable as a edittext in a configuration class. And I just implemented sharedpreferences, so when the user would edit the widget for the second or third time etc. the already inputted text would appear in the edittext field in the configuration class.

And it works I guess. Well, before I implemented the sharedpreferences, the widget would update just fine after configuration. But now, I edit the text, press apply, but the widget doesn't update, I then edit the widget again and the widget updates with the text I applied to it the time before. So i guess you can say, that it's one update delayed. I hope I'm being clear, it's a little hard to explain.

So what am I doing wrong, I can not get it to work, any help would be very much appreciated.

Code:

```
public class WidgetConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    AppWidgetManager awm;
    int awID;
    Context c;
    EditText info;
    Button b;
    String note;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.widgetconfig);

        c = WidgetConfig.this;
        info = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etwidgetconfig);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bwidgetconfig);
        loadPrefs();
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Getting Info about the widget that launched this activity
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID );
        }

        awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);

    }

    private void loadPrefs(){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        note = sp.getString("NOTE", "DEFAULT");

        info.setText(note);

    }

    private void savePrefs(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();       
        editor.putString(key, value); // value to store
        editor.commit();   

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        savePrefs("NOTE", info.getText().toString());

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, note);


        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, Widget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);

        Intent in = new Intent(c, WidgetConfig.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.B_EditAgain, pi);

        awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);


        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually updating the TextView with the value of the EditText field. Your pseudocode currently looks like this:

```
String note;

onCreate(){
    note = getSharedPref(NOTE);
}

onClick(){
    putSharedPref(info.getText());
    views.setText(note);
}
```

This ignores the value in your EditText until the NEXT time that you call onCreate, which you observed.

You should update the views with the text from the EditText:

```
onClick(){
   putSharedPref(info.getText());
   views.setText(info.getText());
}
```

Comment: just the simple quick fix I was hoping for, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!